# SUM acorrding to another column

Tags: php, sql, select, count, sum

I need to know if there is a possible way doing this with out subquery..

Here is my table structure:

```
id-name-father_id
1  joe    0
2  mark   0
3  muller 0
4  miki   2
5  timi   2
6  moses  2
7  david  1
8  momo   0
9  daniel 0
10 ermi   3
```

My table logic is

- `0` means he is not a child of some one
- `1+` mean that he is son of man in that row.

Note: if some one have a child, he still 
will have 0 in father id (it's mean there is not grand-fathers in my table)

My query is :

```
SELECT id, name, count(id=father_id) as sons
WHERE father_id = 0
```

What I want to get is a list of non-children `(father_id=0)` and `sum`
the childrens it has.
Is there a way to get the results without a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it (MySQL):

```
SELECT `parents`.`id`, `parents`.`name`, COUNT(`children`.*) AS sons
FROM `people` AS parents
LEFT JOIN `people` AS children ON `parents`.`id` = `children`.`father_id`
WHERE `parents`.`father_id` = 0
GROUP BY `parents`.`id`
```

According to *Gary* we need to add `name` to `GROUP BY` in other SQL databases:

```
SELECT `parents`.`id`, `parents`.`name`, COUNT(`children`.*) AS sons
FROM `people` AS parents
LEFT JOIN `people` AS children ON `parents`.`id` = `children`.`father_id`
WHERE `parents`.`father_id` = 0
GROUP BY `parents`.`id`, `parents`.`name`
```

We are joing the table with itself here. So we join all parents with their children.

This will lead to a result like that:

```
parents.id  parents.name children.id  children.name
1           joe          7            david
2           mark         4            miki
2           mark         5            timi
2           mark         6            moses
3           muller       10           ermi
8           momo         -            - # left join allows this line
9           daniel       -            -
```

But now we have each parent several times. So we are GROUP'ing the whole thing over the parent’s id, which will result in the following:

```
parents.id  parents.name COUNT(children.*)
1           joe          1
2           mark         3
3           muller       1
8           momo         0
9           daniel       0
```

Comment: I think you need to add parents.name to the group by clause as well

Comment: oops, misunderstood you (the upvote is for reminding me that `name` in SELECT was ambiguous and I needed `parents`.`name`) ;) Why would I need the name in the group by? The ID is already unique, isn’t it? name would not make a difference. Maybe I got the question wrong?

Comment: +1 Worth mentioning that although the same general approach can be used in any SQL, certain features of this query are MySQL-specific (ie. backquoted names and unaggregated, ungrouped columns in the `select` clause of a grouped query).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on MySQL, but other SQL databases I've used (Postgres, Oracle, MSSQL for definite) will require that any column included in the output without going through an aggregate function is mentioned in the GROUP BY clause.   Even if the GROUP BY clause already has a unique key.

Comment: Ok, then I will include it. I only know MySQL. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @Gary: MySQL *doesn't* require it - that was (partly) the point of my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it without any joins or sub-queries as follows:

```
select case father_id when 0 then id else father_id end id,
       max(case father_id when 0 then name end)     name,
       sum(sign(father_id))                         sons
from table
group by case father_id when 0 then id else father_id
```

Comment: i am not familiar with the "case x when y then z " but is it good for performance issues...

Comment: It's not **bad** for performance - in relational databases, it's usually logical accesses of tables that really kill performance. Here, the table is only being accessed once - in theory, it should be faster than any query that accesses the same table more than once, although in practice (particularly if the table is small) this difference may not be significant.